# Object pointer parameter cannot use accessor method from the same class as the object

Tags: c++, syntax-error

So I have this:

```
class A
{
private:
    unsigned int _uid; //user identifier
public:
    A();
    A(const char *, const char *, int, int, const char *, const char *, const char *);
    virtual ~A();
    int getUserID();
};

int A::getUserID(){
    return _uid;
}

//The class UserDB is not that important as this method is at this moment.
void UserDB::adduser(A* newUser){
    if(newUser.getUserID == 0) //Not working, not sure why... Gives syntax error. (1)
    //Something is done if the condition is true;
};

int main(){
    UserDB B
    A tempObj;
    //Assume the 7 following variables have been initialized correctly.
    char uloginName[9];
    char homeDirectory[33];
    int userID;
    int groupID;
    char password[17];
    char shell[17];
    char gecos[65];
    tempObj = new A(uloginName, password, userID, groupID, gecos, homeDirectory, shell);
    B = new UserDB();
    B.addUser(tempObj);
}
```

And so somehow I cannot get the parameter pointer to use the accessor method (refer at line marked by (1)). Can someone give me a quick fix? I searched a for a way to do it but no one seems to have accessors with parameters being pointers to an object.

Comment: I can tell you come from a language with different `new` syntax. Maybe java? :)

Answer (score 2):

You've a number of issues here. Let me try to address some of them for you.

You declare:

```
     unsigned int _uid; //user identifier
```

But your getter for this is:

```
    int getUserID();
```

This risks truncation. It should be:

```
    unsigned int getUserID() const;
```

`const` because you're not modifying the instance of the `class`.

This would be defined:

```
unsigned int A::getUserID() const
{
    return _uid;
}
```

Next up, this method of the phantom `class`:

```
void UserDB::adduser(A* newUser)
```

You said:

> I searched a for a way to do it but no one seems to have accessors with parameters being pointers to an object.

That is because there's no need for this in such a `class`. You should prefer to pass by reference here. `const`-reference would be better, but let's not change too much...

```
void UserDB::adduser(A& newUser)
{
    if (newUser.getUserID() == 0)
    {
        //Something is done if the condition is true;
    }
};
```

No syntax error there! For a pointer, first you'd need to check it's not `NULL` and then use the `->` operator rather then the `.`. References are much cleaner.

Onwards, then, to...

```
int main(){

    A tempObj;
```

This constructs an instance of `A` on the stack, calling the default constructor. You don't need this, so just remove it.

```
    UserDB B;
```

This constructs a `B` on the stack, again calling the default constructor. I'm going to leave it alone.

```
    //Assume the 7 following variables have been initialized correctly.
```

Okay. Just this once.

```
    tempObj = new A(uloginName, password, userID, groupID, gecos, homeDirectory, shell);
```

You can't do that! `tempObj` was an `A`, not an `A*`. Instead just create an `A` on the stack calling the second constructor:

```
    A tempObj(uloginName, password, userID, groupID, gecos, homeDirectory, shell);
```

Now onto...

```
    B = new UserDB();
```

Again, you can't do this. `B` is a `UserDB`, not a `UserDB*`. Just delete this line, it's not needed as you've already created one on the stack!

This line is almost right...

```
    B.addUser(tempObj);
```

...but C++ is case-sensitive! Use:

```
    B.adduser(tempObj);
```

And your code should compile.

Time to [read a book or two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/78845)!

Comment: Thank you, I fixed all these errors a few days ago, but thank you anyway, your answer is very descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that `tempObj` is supposed to be pointer here: `A tempObj = new A();`, so it should look like this:

```
int main()
{
    // ...
    A* tempObj = new A(uloginName, password, userID, groupID, gecos, homeDirectory, shell);
    UserDB B;
    B.addUser(tempObj);
    // ...
    delete tempObj;
    return 0;
}
```

And `if(newUser.getUserID == 0)` is supposed to be `if(newUser->getUserID() == 0)` since you are dealing with pointer and `getUserID` is a method, not a member variable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It tells me I cannot delete B. "Expression must have pointer or handle type"

Comment: Have you declared `B` as a pointer to `UserDB`? It should look like this: `UserDB* B = new UserDB(); /* some code */ delete B;`

Comment: I don't intend to make it a pointer. Assigning it a `new` was a mistake.

Comment: I think that by `delete A` you meant `delete tempObj`, however when I write that I get an error of `expression: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)`

Comment: Yeah, thanks it was typo. And to this heap corruption: make sure you don't try to delete same object twice.

Comment: I just wrote `delete tempObj` once, but yeah, I'll see what else I can do. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Change `if(newUser.getUserID == 0)` to `if(newUser->getUserID() == 0)`
and `B.addUser(tempObj);` to `B->addUser(&tempObj);`

You would also need to declare `tempObj` and  `B` objects as pointer:

```
UserDB* B
A* tempObj;
```

Of course it's not recommended to use pointers if you don't need to because of memory management issues you have to deal with. This is the way to go without pointers:

```
void UserDB::addUser(A newUser)
{
    if(newUser.getUserID() == 0)
    {
        //Something is done if the condition is true;
    } 
};

int main(){    
    //Assume the 7 following variables have been initialized correctly.
    char uloginName[9];
    char homeDirectory[33];
    int userID;
    int groupID;
    char password[17];
    char shell[17];
    char gecos[65];
    UserDB B;
    A tempObj(uloginName, password, userID, groupID, gecos, homeDirectory, shell);
    B.addUser(tempObj);
}
```

To improve performance, it's better to pass `newUser` parameter [by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921554/references-as-function-arguments/8921618#8921618) so that it doesn't get copied when passed to `addUser` method. And make it `const` to make sure that its value doesn't accidentally get modified inside the `addUser` method:

```
void UserDB::addUser(const A &newUser)
{
    if(newUser.getUserID() == 0)
    {
        //Something is done if the condition is true;
    } 
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't give me a syntax error anymore. I hope it works.

Comment: is there a way to keep `B` as `UserDB` type only?

Answer (score 0):

`newUser` is a pointer, so you need either `(*newUser).` or `newUser->` to access what it points to.

To call a function you need to use the function call operator `()`.

Then you get

```
newUser->getUserID()
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried `(*newUser).` but it didn't work. However the second one did.